# Operator overloading equivalent in C++ for PHP, echo/print class variable for default output

Tags: php, c++, object, operator-overloading

I don't know how to really ask this because I am fairly new to programming in comparison to many of you.  What I am looking for is a default printing or echoing of a class.  I'll give you the c++ equivalent.

```
ClassName varClass(param);

cout << "Default print: " << varClass << endl;
```

As you can see in that brief example, instead of having to call `varClass.customPrintFunction()`, I only had to use the variable name.

What I need is the php equivalent to that.  What in php would allow me to do this:

```
$address = new Address(param);

echo "Default print: " . $address . "<br />";
```

Instead of: `echo "Default print: " . $address->customPrintFunction() . "<br />";`

I hope I was clear enough.  If there isn't an equivalent, if you could give me what would be my best option instead.

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1619483/how-to-echo-a-class :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can define a [`__toString`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.magic.php#language.oop5.magic.tostring) method that defines the behavior of the object in case it is cast to a string.

```
public function __toString() { return $this->customPrintFunction(); }
```

Comment: This is definitely what I was looking for, thanks.  I had a suspicion that it what something like this, but I couldn't remember.  I have some memory of seeing this function before but I didn't know what it was for at the time, but now I know.  Thanks.

For clarification, we are assuming the $this->customPrintFunction returns a string.  I wasn't very clear before and that is what my intention was with that function.