# Print class failed with error of parse error: syntax error, unexpected '$userN' (T_VARIABLE)

Tags: php, class, pdo

I saw [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1619483/how-to-echo-a-class) already, tried to manipulate, but failed. I received the error of:

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '$userN' (T_VARIABLE) in ...
```

I tried var_dump, printf, echo and none of them work.

Code:

```
class User {
private $dbh;
public function __construct($host,$user,$pass,$db)  {   ...}
public function getQs(){            ...}
}
$userN=new User(...); 
var_dump $userN;
```

(Note: the `...` are there to hide sensitive information, they are actual code/variable that is valid in place.)

Comment: It looks like that `$userN=new User` is inside your class - is that right? If not, you need to clean up the code - you have way more opening braces than you do closing ones.

Comment: add brackets into var_dump()

Comment: @andrewsi, sry my braces misled you lol, I was just try to represent the function is there, I added the ending ones. Thanks for finding !

Comment: Given the answer, this question can be closed via "Not reproducible or was caused by a typo". While it is good that the problem was solved at the time, it probably will not be useful for future readers.

Answer (score 2):

`var_dump $userN;` should be `var_dump($userN);`

Comment: worked now... my goodness, I always stuck on this type of small things lol Thanks a lot!